# What's the point of hooking register_nav_menu to "init" rather than calling it directly?

Tags: wordpress, menu

The standard method of registering a menu with WordPress consists in adding this to functions.php:

```
function register_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('main_menu', 'Main Menu');
}
add_action('init', 'register_menu');
```

But why not simply calling register_nav_menu() from functions.php without hooking anything?

```
register_nav_menu('main_menu', 'Main Menu');
```

It works fine too so why bother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and most "generally" relevant is that at the time that `functions.php` is loaded, wordpress is not yet fully initialized and as such is not necessarily "stable".  This is less important for something like `register_nav_menu()` but is worth mentioning.

The second reason is that you can't remove something that has been declared "loosely" with [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action).  This, while not necessarily as generally applicable is much more important in many cases.

Consider that in the future you or someone else is creating a child theme based on the theme you are developing now.  There would not be a good way for the child theme to stop your theme from declaring the menu. This is just 1 example and there are other examples of where being able to stop another component from doing something might be important.

These issues may not seem especially relevant when first developing a theme, but as time goes on these types of best-practices issues become a real headache for maintenance.